# Questions on user pages don't show ones with marked answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

When I look at a user page (take [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/998/bobobobo) for example), if the user has asked questions, they show in the Questions list. That's fine and expected. However, if the user has marked a question as answered, it does not indicate that unless you click the "View More" link.

Above, in the Answers list, it shows whether or not the user's answer was accepted, so why wouldn't it show it in the Questions list? On stackoverflow this [works as I'd expect](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111307/bobobobo) , so I think this may just be a styling issue or a bug that was overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was indeed just a styling issue. Fixed after the next build of the sites (here as well as on english.se and android.se, and the respective metas; all of these had the same issue).

Thanks!

Comment: Is this fixed now or will there be an update later? I don't see it any differently.

Comment: As I said, "after the next build of the sites". This usually happens at least once a day, ofter more times. But not immediately.

Comment: Oh, haha. I'm dumb. In one eye and out the other? :)